# Why is index always 23 when handleClick() is called. REACT

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am learning React by following concepts from the tic-tac-toe tutorial. I am trying to create an online course providing platform. I have a bunch of filter buttons, each indicating a topic for course, for example, "Applied Mathematics". Since, there are a lot of filter buttons to display, I created an array of filter buttons, by populating them from a filter list array - which contains relevant data for each filter. This is the function that does this:

```
    renderFilters() {
            this.filterButtonList = [];
            for (var index in this.filterList) {
                index = parseInt(index);
                var item = (
                    <FilterButton
                        key={this.filterList[index].param}
                        text={this.filterList[index].text}
                        param={this.filterList[index].param}
                        isActive={this.state.isActive[index]}
                        onClick={() => {
                            this.handleClick.bind(index);
                            this.handleClick(index);
                        }}
                    />
                );
                this.filterButtonList.push(item);
            }
            return this.filterButtonList;
        }
```

This function is called in the render function of the component we are concerned with:

```
    render() {
            return <div className="filters">{this.renderFilters()}</div>;
    }
```

The filter list looks something like this:

```
    this.filterList = [
                { text: "All Topics", param: "all-topics" },
                { text: "Algorithms and Data Structures", param: "#cat=engineering&subcat=computerscience&spec=algorithmsanddatastructures" },
                { text: "Artificial Intelligence", param: "#cat=engineering&subcat=computerscience&spec=artificialintelligence" },
                { text: "Computer Design and Engineering", param: "#cat=engineering&subcat=computerscience&spec=computerdesignandengineering" },
                { text: "Computer Networks", param: "#cat=engineering&subcat=computerscience&spec=computernetworks" },
                { text: "Cryptography", param: "#cat=engineering&subcat=computerscience&spec=cryptography" },
                { text: "Data Mining", param: "#cat=engineering&subcat=computerscience&spec=datamining" },
                { text: "Graphics and Visualization", param: "#cat=engineering&subcat=computerscience&spec=graphicsandvisualization" },
                { text: "Human-Computer Interfaces", param: "#cat=engineering&subcat=computerscience&spec=humancomputerinterfaces" },
                { text: "Operating Systems", param: "#cat=engineering&subcat=computerscience&spec=operatingsystems" },
                { text: "Programming Languages", param: "#cat=engineering&subcat=computerscience&spec=programminglanguages" },
                { text: "Software Design and Engineering", param: "#cat=engineering&subcat=computerscience&spec=softwaredesignandengineering" },
                { text: "Theory of Computation", param: "#cat=engineering&subcat=computerscience&spec=theoryofcomputation" },
                { text: "Algebra and Number Theory", param: "#cat=mathematics&subcat=algebraandnumbertheory" },
                { text: "Applied Mathematics", param: "#cat=mathematics&subcat=appliedmathematics" },
                { text: "Calculus", param: "#cat=mathematics&subcat=calculus" },
                { text: "Computation", param: "#cat=mathematics&subcat=computation" },
                { text: "Differential Equations", param: "#cat=mathematics&subcat=differentialequations" },
                { text: "Discrete Mathematics", param: "#cat=mathematics&subcat=discretemathematics" },
                { text: "Linear Algebra", param: "#cat=mathematics&subcat=linearalgebra" },
                { text: "Mathematical Analysis", param: "#cat=mathematics&subcat=mathematicalanalysis" },
                { text: "Mathematical Logic", param: "#cat=mathematics&subcat=mathematicallogic" },
                { text: "Probability and Statistics", param: "#cat=mathematics&subcat=probabilityandstatistics" },
                { text: "Topology and Geometry", param: "#cat=mathematics&subcat=topologyandgeometry" },
            ];
```

And, the implementation for the `<FilterButton>` is this:

```
    class FilterButton extends React.Component {
        render() {
            return (
                <button
                    className={this.props.isActive === "true" ? "filters-button active" : "filters-button"}
                    onClick={() => {
                        this.props.onClick();
                    }}
                >
                    {this.props.text}
                </button>
            );
        }
    }
```

The implementation for `handleClick(i)` is this:

```
    handleClick(i) {
        //Nothing fancy, just trying to display the value of the passed index.
        console.log(i);
    }
```

However, clicking on any of the buttons only prints "23", rather than printing the index of the button clicked - for example, if I click on "All Topics" button - which has a index of "0" in this filter list, it should print "0", not "23". The same is true, if instead of index I passed something like `this.filterList[index].text` to display the button text - in which case, if I click on something like "Applied Mathematics" button or "Linear Algebra" button, it only prints "Topology and Geometry" (which is the value from last row of filter list). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Because later, when the click is done, that's the value `index` has. The same `index` variable is shared by all of those callbacks. See the linked question's answers for details.

Comment: Side note: `for-in` is rarely the correct way to loop through an array. Details and alternatives in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9329476/157247). Combining that with the answers linked above: `for (let index = 0; index < this.filterList.length; ++index) {` When you use `let` to declare a `for` loop variable, a *different* variable is created for each loop iteration, and each callback closes over its own copy.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I am reading those answers :)

Comment: That simple fix solved the problem, REALLY REALLY THANKS A LOT :D God bless you